# TypeScript: undefined is not a function

Tags: typescript, undefined

I've the following ts-class:

```
class TrackerManager {

public _csTrackers: DevExpress.data.CustomStore;
public _dbOptions: DevExpress.data.CustomStoreOptions;
private SERVICE_URL_GET_TRACKERS: string = 'xx'
private SERVICE_URL_UPDATE_TRACKER: string = 'xx'
private SERVICE_URL_GET_GPSSYSTEMS: string = 'xx'

constructor() {
    this.initTrackersCustomStoreSettings();
}

private initTrackersCustomStoreSettings(): void {
    this._dbOptions = {
        load: function (loadOptions):any {
            debugger;
            return this.SendRequest(this.SERVICE_URL_GET_TRACKERS, 'GET');
        },
        insert: function (params):any {
            //return dbImpl._sendRequest(SERVICE_URL_UPDATE_TRACKER, 'POST', params);
        },
    };
}

public SendRequest(myurl: string, t: string): any {
    //ToDo
}

public getTrackerCustomStore(): DevExpress.data.CustomStore {
    this._csTrackers = new DevExpress.data.CustomStore(this._dbOptions);
    return this._csTrackers;
}
```

}

When load is called, can anyone tell me why this.SendRequest is undefined? And what I have to change?

I'm new to typescript.

Thank you very much.
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

Right now the JavaScript output of your code is the following:

```
TrackerManager.prototype.initTrackersCustomStoreSettings = function () {
    this._dbOptions = {
        load: function (loadOptions) {
            debugger;
            return this.SendRequest(this.SERVICE_URL_GET_TRACKERS, 'GET');
        },
        // omitted...
    };
};
```

As you can see, the value of `this` will not be preserved.

**Solution**

To fix this, use an arrow function to preserve the context:

```
private initTrackersCustomStoreSettings(): void {
    this._dbOptions = {
        load: (loadOptions) => {
            debugger;
            return this.SendRequest(this.SERVICE_URL_GET_TRACKERS, 'GET');
        },
        // omitted...
    };
}
```

Which will transpile to the following javascript:

```
TrackerManager.prototype.initTrackersCustomStoreSettings = function () {
    var _this = this; // notice this new variable and how it's used
    this._dbOptions = {
        load: function (loadOptions) {
            debugger;
            return _this.SendRequest(_this.SERVICE_URL_GET_TRACKERS, 'GET');
        },
        // omitted...
    };
};
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but still everyhing is undefined (e.g. this.SendRequest, this._dbOptions, this.SERVICE_URL_GET_TRACKERS) when im in the load function. It looks like I have no access to my class methods/variables. Any other idea?

Comment: Additional: Sorry, it should work now as you wrote. Thanks a lot! I was irritated that the chrome debugger debugs the ts file and still shows undefined, but when I continue it jumps into SendRequest, what is correct. Thank you again!

Comment: @user1539859 no problem! When you said it didn't work I thought it was probably some cache issue. I've had that problem with chrome before too.

Answer (score -1):

Since you haven't implemented the `SendRequest` method yet, it doesn't return a value.  So when you try to return the result of `SendRequest`, you get undefined.

Comment: this.SendRequest is not the only thing which is undefined. When I look at runtime, as soon as I get into load function, everything is undefined (e.g. this._dbOptions, this.SERVICE_URL_GET_TRACKERS). It looks like I have no access to my class. Any other idea?